# How do I remove duplicate values within a column throughout the dataset in R

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, columnsorting

The dataframe looks like the following:

```
        var_1 var_2 var_3
        5     2     2
        5     2     1
        6     3     4
```

**dput of data**

```r
data <- structure(list(var_1 = c(5L, 5L, 6L), var_2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L), 
  var_3 = c(2L, 1L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I remove duplicate values within a column, and repeat this for all columns so the data looks like:

```
       var_1 var_2 var_3
       5     2     2
       6     3     1
                   4
```

Comment: I assume you want `NA` there rather than converting to character to have a blank string ""?

Comment: Thanks for responding Jon. NA would work. Ultimately, I'd like to sum each individual column so having NA would be fine if that's the simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach, pivoting longer, filtering for distinct column-value combinations, then spreading:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  distinct(name, value) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    row var_1 var_2 var_3
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5     2     2
2     2     6     3     1
3     3    NA    NA     4
```

If you want the sum of distinct numbers, you could add as a last line:

```
%>% summarize(across(-row, ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  var_1 var_2 var_3
  <int> <int> <int>
1    11     5     7
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! If I want to summarize 50 variable columns not 3 how do I add columns 1 to 50, and then write out a csv file? Thanks

Comment: Edited, you could use `-row` to characterize the row you don't want to summarize, or else filter it out first with `select(-row) %>% summarize(across(everything(), ~sum...`

Comment: I tried %>%summarize(across(everything(), ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) but it doesn't seem to work. Alternatively, how can I write out the csv file after your code line pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)?

Comment: Does the edited `%>% summarize(across(-row, ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))` work? If you want to export, see `write_csv` or you could try `clipr::write_clip` to paste into something else.

Answer (score 0):

A try return a list with different length after unique. In `data.frame` you always need them to have equal length with `NA` filled in

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)
data <- structure(list(var_1 = c(5L, 5L, 6L), var_2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L), 
  var_3 = c(2L, 1L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

# get unique lsit
map(data, unique)
#> $var_1
#> [1] 5 6
#> 
#> $var_2
#> [1] 2 3
#> 
#> $var_3
#> [1] 2 1 4

# get unique & sum in one take
map(data, function(x) { sum(unique(x)) })
#> $var_1
#> [1] 11
#> 
#> $var_2
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $var_3
#> [1] 7
```

**Shorter version with summarize if only need to calculate the sum of unique value**

```
# if all you need is the sum of unique value then you can just do this
data %>%
  summarize(across(.fns = function(x) { sum(unique(x)) }))
#>   var_1 var_2 var_3
#> 1    11     5     7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>
<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**base**

```r
data <- structure(list(var_1 = c(5L, 5L, 6L), var_2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L), 
                       var_3 = c(2L, 1L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")




tmp <- sapply(data, unique)

res <- sapply(tmp, "length<-", max(lengths(tmp)))
res
#>      var_1 var_2 var_3
#> [1,]     5     2     2
#> [2,]     6     3     1
#> [3,]    NA    NA     4
colSums(res, na.rm = T)
#> var_1 var_2 var_3 
#>    11     5     7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>